# Наушник АВС Xperia нашепчет прогноз погоды - нужны ли кавычки в глаголе?

Tags: пунктуация

Наушник ABC Хperia нашепчет прогноз погоды на завтра.

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от желания автора: хочет он или нет придать особый смысл этому глаголу. Обычно никаких кавычек нет. Здесь троп - метонимия. Говорим "наушник нашепчет" , подразумеваем "голос нашепчет". Точно так же, как "класс рассмеялся". Мы же знаем, что смеётся не класс, а люди в классе, но никаких кавычек не ставим, и так всё ясно.